# pivot table in pandas with multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
  date        prod    hourly_bucket      tank      trans      flag     
  01-01-2019  TP      05:00:00-06:00:00  2         Preset     Peak
  01-01-2019  TP      05:00:00-06:00:00  2         Preset     Peak
  01-01-2019  TP      05:00:00-06:00:00  2         Non Preset Peak
  02-01-2019  TP      05:00:00-06:00:00  2         Preset     Lean
  02-01-2019  TP      05:00:00-06:00:00  2         Preset     Lean
  02-01-2019  TP      05:00:00-06:00:00  2         Non Preset Lean
```

My Desired dataframe would be aggregation at day level and tank level and then taking a count of how many `Preset,Non-Preset` transactions in `Lean and Peak` hours

```
  date       tank   Lean_Non_Preset  Lean_Preset  Peak_Non_Preset  Peak_Preset
  01-01-2019 2      1                2            1                2
```

I am doing following in pandas

```
 lean_peak_preset_cnt = df.pivot_table(index=['date','tank'], columns=['flag'],values=['trans'],aggfunc='count').reset_index()
```

But it does not give me the required solution

Comment: Feel free to rollback my edit if i made desired output wrong.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add `'trans'` to parameter `columns` and then flatten `MultiIndex` in columns with `map` and `join`:

```
lean_peak_preset_cnt = df.pivot_table(index=['date','tank'], 
                                      columns=['flag','trans'],
                                      aggfunc='size', 
                                      fill_value=0) 

lean_peak_preset_cnt.columns = lean_peak_preset_cnt.columns.map('_'.join)
lean_peak_preset_cnt = lean_peak_preset_cnt.reset_index() 
print (lean_peak_preset_cnt)

         date  tank  Lean_No Preset  Lean_Preset  Peak_Non Preset  Peak_Preset
0  01-01-2019     2               0            0                1            2
1  02-01-2019     2               1            2                0            0
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there:

```
piv = (df.pivot_table(index=['date', 'tank'], columns=['trans', 'flag'], 
                      aggfunc='size', fill_value=0))
piv.columns = piv.columns.ravel()
```

The size function gives the counts you want, you would want to fill non-counted values with 0, and specify the columns and index you want. See [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) for more details. The [`ravel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.ravel.html) combines your multiindex columns to one level.

```
                 (Nonpreset, Lean)  (Nonpreset, Peak)  (Preset, Lean)  \
#date       tank                                                         
#01-01-2019 2                     0                  1               0   
#02-01-2019 2                     1                  0               2   

                 (Preset, Peak)  
#date       tank                  
#01-01-2019 2                  2  
#02-01-2019 2                  0
```